# Where did the term manifold come from?

Tags: terminology, manifolds, math-history

I first heard the word manifold in regards to an exhaust manifold of a car.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_manifolds_and_varieties) says the term was introduced by Riemann. Riemann lived 1826-1866 and the combustion engine was also developed around this time, maybe a bit earlier than Riemann's time.

Did the mathematical term manifold come first or was it used elsewhere? Why was the word manifold chosen to be used in mathematics?

Comment: I just googled manifold etymology and [this](https://www.etymonline.com/word/manifold)  came up

Comment: Both the car application and the math application boil down, basically, to "many." For cars, it's connections to pipes. For math, it's dimensions. But I have to admit that when I first bought Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds*, I wondered how one did calculus on intake/exhaust manifolds.

Comment: @Rahul If you read my post, you'll see I've linked the Wikipedia page already.

Comment: Fair enough, but if you read the Wikipedia page, you'll see it answers your question of why the word manifold was chosen to be used in mathematics already.

Comment: @TedShifrin Lol  :p